# Where are Hasura migrations stored in DB?

Tags: hasura

- I have a Hasura project with 3 environments: local, staging and prod
- In order to develop locally with the latest data from PROD, I have written a script that dumps and restores PROD db locally
- However, when trying to migrate the locally restored PROD db, I run into issues because the migration state is corrupted. Some migrations have been ran on PROD but they appear as not ran locally although it is exactly the same db.
- When running `hasura migrate status` against PROD and local, I do see different results indeed
- Howeve,r when inspecting the table `hbd_catalog.schema_migrations` on PROD and locally it contains exactly the same data...

What's even more confusing is that although PROD **correctly** marks some of my migrations as ran, their timestamp is not present in the migration table on PROD db...

Is there some other place that Hasura uses to keep track of these migrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Hasura are you using? In Hasura 1.x the `schema_migrations` table was the location for tracking migrations but in in Hasura 2.x this got changed and they are now stored in the `hdb_version` table as a JSON blob in the `cli_state` column.

I had similar confusion after upgrading from 1.x to 2.x because the `schema_migrations` table is still left behind which made me thing it was still in use, but any records there are just vestigial and you can safely delete the table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer! This has broken my workflow and I've created an issue there: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/7610

Comment: Oh wow just looked at the issue you opened. Its really unfortunate that the migration information is hidden from you when using the hosted cloud offering. Hope for your sake that they address this soon

Comment: @JesseCarter Interesting. Hasura team did not mention it in upgrade instuctions? Maybe it's better to tel them to do that

Comment: @AlexYu Better to tell them to do what, delete the table? I self host Hasura so that is not an option but even so I did a fair bit of testing on the new migrations storage in order to determine that the old `schema_migrations` table was being fully ignored

Comment: @JesseCarter It would be great if hasura team wrote a bit more for [hdb_catalog](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/how-it-works/metadata-schema.html#hdb-catalog-schema) than: "This section is a work in progress. There have been other tables and columns added to the catalogue to support new features since this was last updated."